# Get NameIdentifier claim in Azure App Services using OnlineIdAuthenticator

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, azure-web-app-service, claims, azure-mobile-services

I am using the OnlineIdAuthenticator class to get an authentication token in order to log in to Azure App Services, but I'm unable to get the NameIdentifier claim server side. I need the Id to uniquely identify a user and store it in a database.

I want to use the OnlineIdAuthenticator to enable single sign on, so the user isn't prompted to login every time he starts my app (a Windows Store App).

I use this method in my app to get the token and login:

```
    protected override async Task<bool> LoginAsync()
    {
        var authenticator = new OnlineIdAuthenticator();

        var mobileServicesTicket = new OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest("myapp.azurewebsites.net", "JWT");

        var ticketRequests = new List<OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest>() { mobileServicesTicket };

        var authResult = await authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync(ticketRequests, CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded);

        if ((authResult.Tickets.Count == 1) && (authResult.Tickets[0].ErrorCode == 0))
        {
            var accessToken = authResult.Tickets[0];

            var token = new JObject();
            token.Add("authenticationToken", accessToken.Value);

            var _mobileServiceClient = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMobileServiceClient>();
            var user = await _mobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, token);

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Server side I use this method to get the unique Id:

```
    public static async Task<string> GetUserId(IPrincipal pricipal, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {         
        ProviderCredentials credentials = await pricipal.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>(request);
        return credentials.Provider + ":" + credentials.Claims[ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier];
    }
```

The Claims collection above contain these keys:

ver, iss, exp, uid, aud, urn:microsoft:appuri, urn:microsoft:appid

Everything else seems to work. I'm able to login with my MicrosoftAccount and I can call methods that require authentication, but I'm just not able to generate the user id.

How can I get the NameIdentifier in the Claims collection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var claims = principal.Claims;
var oid = claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault();
```